# SSL operation failed with code 1 whit smtp

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

After December 3, i cant send Emails whit smtp from php (Codeigniter), i have not changed anything, I do not know what is happening.
Does anyone know if there is any update that left some function obsolete in some version of PHP?

```
Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Filename: libraries/Email.php
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe there is slight possibility certificate expired on that date?

Comment: in fact I never had a certificate. even so the application worked correctly, and I never had problems of that kind, nor have I made any changes in the services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this problem.
I realized that there is a lot of disinformation on the internet about this topic.

**I hope this can be useful!**

If you running PHP 5.3.7 or later.

1. Generate an vbs file from this file.
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/curl/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.vbs
2. Open a Command Prompt as Administrator and run

   C:>mk-ca-bundle.vbs
3. After finish that process you need to modify the php.ini.

   openssl.cafile=C:\ca-bundle.crt
4. Restart the IIS web site and its all